# Conditional Type on props value

Tags: typescript

Hi everyone I'm trying to create an interface for my function

```ts
interface IManageActions {
  action: "add" | "remove" | "edit";
  element: AddExtra;
  list: AddExtra[];
  indextoEdit: typeof action extends "edit" ? number : undefined;
}
```

The objectif is that if the value of action is edit I want to have a indexToEdit else this parameter should be undefind or not mention. I don't think it's possible the way I tried it.

it's why I tried an other solution.

```ts
interface IManageActions {
  action: "add" | "remove" | "edit";
  element: AddExtra;
  list: AddExtra[];
}
interface IManageActionsEdit {
  action: "edit";
  element: AddExtra;
  list: AddExtra[];
  indextoEdit: number;
}

function manageActions({
  action,
  element,
  list,
  indextoEdit,
}: IManageActions | IManageActionsEdit){}
```

but now the following error occured.

> Property 'indextoEdit' does not exist on type 'IManageActions | IManageActionsEdit

I would like to find a clean way to do it.

thanks for your answers

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAggJnAogD2AJwIZQLxQN4C+A3AFAmiRQCSAshgHYYDmEMAxsAJYD29AzjnxQIAGwgBbCPWAAuWAhToMRKCM59Z8pKkwBtALpQCUAGRQAFCShQAPvivXHGDj3pyA5BDidg70g8coTno4CFRuRG9NegBXcQAjCDRSQIIHOzwApxdeDwwEd1sodzQJbgA3CD8s62DQ8MifAH45eghK5Ky0gEpSIA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: the two solution are quite similar but I think the one from @wonderflame is cleaner thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a [distributive union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). Let's extract the common fields first:

```
type CommonFields = { element: AddExtra; list: AddExtra[] }
```

Now, let's create the whole type, where the `indexToEdit` will be only mentioned where the `action: 'edit'`:

```
type IManageActions = CommonFields & (
  | {
    action: 'edit';
    indextoEdit: number;
  }
  | {
    action: 'add' | 'remove';
  }
)
```

However, this way `indextoEdit` still won't be accessible because it doesn't exist in the variations. The solution would be to add the `indexToEdit` to the other variant and make it optional with of type `never`:

```
type AddExtra = {};

type CommonFields = { element: AddExtra; list: AddExtra[] }

type IManageActions = CommonFields & (
  | {
    action: 'edit';
    indextoEdit: number;
  }
  | {
    action: 'add' | 'remove';
    indextoEdit?: never;
  }
);
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAggJnAogD2AJwIZQLxQN4C+A3AFAmiRQDCA9gLZ00B2AYgJYQA2cAzjvlC4Q6EJsABcsBCnQYiUTmx4SpSVJgDaAXSgEyFaAEkAshiYYA5hBgBjYG2Z9ctBs3ZdeUAGRQAFCSgoAB98AMCoDDsHJkkAcgg4NmBY0nCoNiY4CFQaRESVJgBXOgAjCDRU3TCQvDDAyPtmOIwEWOCoWLRhGgA3CBS69Mzs4Fz8gH5JJgg+irC9AEpSIA)